# How to create a skewed column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, distribution

I would like to create a new column in a dataframe with a skewed distribution. I would like it to have 64000 data points, with a minimum of 0 (no negative values), and some sort of skewed shape where most people are closer to 0 and then it levels off to the right with higher values.

I have tried this but I am unable to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
rv = skewnorm.rvs(400000, size=100000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) or [poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) distribution depending on what you are after exactly. **The exponential distribution will give continuous values while poisson will give discrete values.** Both can be found in the `numpy` package. After creating the `numpy` array, it can easily be added to a `pandas` dataframe.

**Exponential distribution ([numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html)):**

```
import numpy as np

beta = 10
s = np.random.exponential(beta, 64000)
```

`beta` acts as a scale parameter and will determine how large the values will be while keeping the general distribution shape. Plotwith `beta=10` and 100 bins:

[image: Exponential plot]

**Poisson distribution ([numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html)):**

```
import numpy as np

lam = 0.9
s = np.random.poisson(lam , 64000)
```

The rate parameter `lam` will determine the shape of the distribution. Both the mean value and the variance will be equal to `lam`. Note that only discrete values are obtained. Plot with `lam=0.9` and 8 bins:

[image: Poisson plot]

Comment: [Triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) with a mode close to (or at) zero would be another option if there's a fixed upper bound.